# zebra/candy/loading bar stripes help

Tags: javascript, html, css, candy

I am building my portfolio but I can`t remember in what coding language I could build such ,vertical or horizontal, animated candy stripes loading bars to showcase my skills.
What can I use to build such things?

Comment: Could you link to an example of something similar?

Comment: There's a wonderful new website called Google that can answer these kinds of questions for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.cssjockey.com/web-development/an-easy-way-to-create-loading-bar

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for some sexy [CSS Progress Bars](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/) with Animated Candystriping? Or maybe an [Ajax Loader](http://www.ajaxload.info/) is more your style?

[image]

[image]